# Riemann integral of discrete white noise

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, riemann-integration, stochastic-differential-equations, noise

I have a time series of values from a Gaussian white noise which are evenly spaced ($\Delta t$). I'd like to approximate
$$\int_{0}^{T}\mathsf{A}(t)\mathbf{f}(t) \,\mathrm{d}t$$
where $\mathbf{f}$ is the Gaussian white noise, "A" arbitrary. In my case, I have a discrete set of N realisations of this, and so my first thought was to numerically integrate with
$$\sum_{i=0}^{N}\mathsf{A}(t_i)\mathbf{f}(t_i)\Delta t$$
I've seen some examples similar to this online, but the world of SDEs is hinting that I should, in fact, be writing
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{N}\mathsf{A}(t_i)\mathbf{f}(t_i)\sqrt{\Delta t}$$
based on the idea that white noise integrates to give Brownian/red noise, and the properties of Wiener processes  should then be followed.

I'm no expert in this area, so which (if either) is the correct choice, and, intuitively, why?

---

Bonus question!
My data are of course not truly "white" at all time scales, and have a decorrelation time, say $\lambda$. How can I correctly include this so that any time units drop out of the result? If I should use  $\sqrt{\Delta t}$, should it actually be $\sqrt{\frac{\Delta t}{\lambda}}$?